# Issue with Monte Carlo Simulation on an interest rate tree in Excel

Tags: interest-rates, monte-carlo, excel, bdt

I need to build a Monte Carlo simulation model that does 10 iterations on the interest rate tree. I need to identify the interest rate given a sequence of moving up and down the interest rate tree. I managed to create an IF statement until i=2, however it gets tricky on i=3 onwards.

Any suggestions? I was told to use the INDEX() function, but I fail to see how I can use it as a condition.

Thanks!

EDIT: This is what I have on node 2 -> =IF(U4="up",IF(X4="up",D10,D11),IF(X4="up",D11,D12))

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Well, you make it too complicated. An easy way is to count how many "up"s or "down"s before that node. For example, for the node 3, there can be 3 ups 0 downs, 2 ups 1 downs, 1 ups 2 downs, 0 ups 3 downs. 3 ups 0 downs will point to 0.0495. 2 ups 1 downs is 0.0251.....

So no matter the ups/downs sequence, only the numbers of ups/downs can tell you the answer.